# Как обработать множественный выбор в ListBox WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Каким образом можно обработать множественный выбор элементов в ListBox, т.к SelectionIndexChanged срабатывает только при выборе одного элемента в ListBox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну вот вам пример.

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <ListBox SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple" Name="LB"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TB" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="LightGray"/>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        OnSelectionChanged(null, null);
    }

    void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItems = LB.SelectedItems.Cast<int>();
        var s = string.Join(", ", selectedItems);
        if (s == "")
            s = "(none)";
        TB.Text = $"Selected items: {s}";
    }
}
```

Получается вот что:

[image: анимашка]

---

Если вы используете MVVM и хотите обрабатывать выделение на уровне VM, лучше завести свойство `IsSelected` в `ItemVM`, переопределить стиль контейнера

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

и подписаться на изменение `IsSelected` в `ItemVM`. Но это может оказаться и не вполне хороший путь, т. к. выбранные элементы всё же визуальное свойство.

Comment: Давненько вас не было видно  Приветствую.

Comment: @Bulson: Ну, это я случайно мимо крокодил. И я вас приветствую :)

Comment: Ого, вот это люди! Рад тебя видеть с нами, даже если просто мимо крокодил!

Comment: @tym32167: Взаимно! 